# Как реализовать подписку на изменение в базе данных ( api - Django, client - Node.js )?

Tags: node.js, django

Вообщем есть 2 сервера, один сервер с телеграмм ботом на Node, другой это REST Api Django. Задумка такая, если в Django произошло какое-то изменение, то об этом надо уведомить сервер с телеграмм ботом, чтобы он разослал всем подписанным уведомление об этом. Но я не догадываюсь, как это реализовать. Какие технологии/библиотеки надо использовать на бэкенде и клиенте, чтобы реализовать подписку?

Comment: как написали, так и реализовывать. подписку можно организовать примерно 10-20 (50?) разными способами. Вам нужно где-то хранить пользователей и их подписки.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Прошу, укажите хотя бы на 1 способ